# Android - Creating listview with floating headers

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, user-interface, view

Targeting 2.3 - 4.2 I would like to implement the following effect (see image), basically a group list where next item header pushes the last one.

What would be the best approach?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you will have to use a 3rd party library to do this as this is not built into the SDK

[StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) does exactly what you want